# Java script error when connecting to LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

*"Happy New Year.."*
  problem occurred when we are trying to connect Linked via javascript. I have follow and the spend given in developers.linkedIn.com but its showing below error.

> userspace?v=0.0.1199-RC8.53274-1429&apiKey='75b4....do0'&secure=1&:22 Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.

I have created a subdomain http://vclinkedin.deepeshuniyal.in and fill all details in linkedIn site properly.
the domain is working properly.

below is my html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
            api_key: '75b4....do0'
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- need to be logged in to use Search; if not, offer a login button -->
    <script type="IN/Login"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is a "Java script"?

Comment: I would expect the API key (which you may want to obfuscate) to not be in quotes `'75b4...0'`

Comment: I was correct and it was REALLY easy to find by simply searching for the error message